# Wait for threads to write changes in the shutdownhook

Tags: java, h2, shutdown-hook

I Have a shutdownhook, that is executed when the process is terminated. However the changes that the program makes to the h2 database are not persistent. Only if I let the shutdown thread wait some time after the commit, I will see the changes in the DB when I strat up again.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // H2 db add row, commit and close
        Thread.sleep(1000); // in try/catch
        System.out.println("Shutdown complete");
    }
}
```

Only with a `sleep`, I will see the changes next time I connect to the DB.

Does anybody know how to wait for the H2 database to finish the operation before the process terminated? I want to avoid a `Thread.sleep()` with a random time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`SHUTDOWN`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#shutdown) command in order to properly flush all writes to disk before closing your application.

An alternative solution would be to call [`CHECKPOINT SYNC`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#checkpoint_sync) in your shutdown hook (but before closing all connections). This would not "close" the database which should be done automatically anyway when the last connection is closed.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove *Thread.sleep()* by using Executors, use its submit method to submit an instance of callable and then use **ExecuterServcie -awaitTermination()** method or you have an option to use is **CountDownLatch -countDown()** method. refer to [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) and [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)